Why is my Windows laptop not querying local DNS server?
I have a local PowerDNS server on a Linux box. I can access it fine on my Windows laptop under Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). dig @main probitas returns the expected address. ping probitas and lynx http://probitas also work on WSL.
Windows DNS settings are configured to use the local server, but in Windows Firefox "http://probitas" fails and "ping probitas" on Windows terminal fails.
The Windows network adapter first DNS server 192.168.0.100 (local PowerDNS server) and second is 192.168.0.1 (router). I can access the Internet, but Windows does not seem to use the DNS settings I entered. What's wrong?

Try without any other DNS servers set. // To diagnose what’s actually happening on the network, I suggest using a packet sniffer like Wireshark. You’ll be able to see where DNS queries are going and what their contents are.

Are you making TLDs out of all your hostnames, or is there a search domain involved that you omitted from the description? If the latter, did you remember to tell Windows to use that search domain?

When I set both DNS addresses to my local server (192.168.0.100) I can connect from Windows (ping, etc. responds as expected). So it seems Windows is only using 192.168.0.1 (my router) when I enable it and ignores my local server. Why?

Yes all of my local host names are set as TLDs.

Huh. Whaddaya know...? I set both DNS addresses to my local server then set one back to my router as it had been before... but now it works! Oh well...
